Handling MySQL's date_format Function in H2 Database for Testing
I am currently facing a challenge with testing a Spring Boot application that uses MySQL in production. Specifically, I'm having trouble with the date_format function, which works perfectly in MySQL but is not supported in the H2 database used for our tests.
Problem
Our application uses the date_format function extensively in repository queries to format dates. These queries work without issues in the production environment with MySQL. However, when running tests that use an H2 database, these queries fail because H2 does not recognize the date_format function.
Example Query
@Query("SELECT e FROM EmployeeEntity e WHERE DATE_FORMAT(e.joinedDate,'%Y%m') = :joinedMonth")
List<Employee> findByJoinedMonth(@Param("joinedMonth") String joinedMonth);


Note: If you are actually calling the database, then strictly speaking you are not executing a unit test, you are executing an integration test.  Unit tests should not be calling any actual database.  And for integreation tests, you should always use the same database in all environments.

@TimBiegeleisen
Thank you for highlighting the distinction between unit tests and integration tests. You're correct; our database-interacting tests are integration tests.
We use H2 for its configuration ease and speed in testing environments. While MySQL is used in production, H2's in-memory capabilities expedite test execution and simplify setup.
We acknowledge the importance of environment consistency and understand the risks of using different databases. Using H2 is a compromise due to logistical constraints, and we carefully handle database-specific functions to mitigate potential issues

Hasn't that done you the favour of showing you that you should be doing the formatting in your code instead of relying on non-portable DB functions?

Worked Solution (tested with Hibernate 6.2.5.Final)
Using Custom H2 Dialect to add our custom function: date_format
1. Create my customer H2 dialect
package com.mycompany.myproject.dialect;

import org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributions;
import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

/**
 * Custom H2 Dialect to add custom functions
 */
public class CustomH2Dialect extends H2Dialect {
    @Override
    public void initializeFunctionRegistry(FunctionContributions functionContributions) {
        super.initializeFunctionRegistry(functionContributions);

        // Registering the DATE_FORMAT function to use H2's FORMATDATETIME function
        functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().register(
                "date_format",
                new StandardSQLFunction("FORMATDATETIME", StandardBasicTypes.STRING)
        );
    }
}

2. Config in /test/application.yaml to use my custom dialect when doing the UT
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: com.mycompany.myproject.dialect.CustomH2Dialect

